# Не работает тестовый пример Angular

Tags: angularjs

Читаю [туториал по Angular](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)
Хожу по "try it now"
вот [один из примеров](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing_otherwise)
Все работает прекрасно.
Сохраняю к себе в папку:
  index.html
  main.htm - копия london.html
  london.htm
  paris.htm

запускаю - получаю ошибку. К тому же в index.html пришлось исправить ссылку в head

ошибка :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Docs/angular/main.htm. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

angular.js:12520 Error: [$compile:tpload]

что я не так делаю? мне бы сохранить пример локально и запустить в браузере и дальше экспериментировать по своему усмотрению.

Comment: так и задумано, запускать надо на локальном сервере, при запуске как обычный файл (по протоколу `file:///`) - не работают ajax запросы, а ими сделаны все подгрузки шаблонов.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest не работает локально, для того, чтобы играться с этим потребуется сервер

Comment: @Grundy понятно, можно оформить как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения с использованием ангуляра не рассчитаны на запуск на локальном сервере, так как загрузка шаблонов из отдельный файлов осуществляется обычным ajax запросом.

В то же время, при открытии просто файла html в браузере, будет использован протокол `file:///` для которого запрещены ajax запросы, из-за этого происходит ошибка при загрузке шаблона и все приложение падает.

В качестве обходного пути можно воспользоваться возможность размещать шаблоны в тегах `script` с типом `type="text/ng-template"`.

Таким образом пример можно заставить работать перенеся все шаблоны в основной файл в теги скрипт и присвоив им `id` соответствующие запрашиваемым адресам, например:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="path/to/template">...</script>
```